# Initialize static variable inside the header file using template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, static

Initialization of a static variable at the header file by using the templates (Used c++11, the 'inline' approach not supported)

cat base_class.hpp

```
#include <string>
#ifndef PROGRAM_BASE
#define PROGRAM_BASE
template <typename T>
struct S
{
    static std::string s_elfName;
};

template <typename T>
std::string S<T>::s_elfName; //static initialization

class program_base : public S<void>{
    public:

    static std::string GetElfName() { return S<std::string>::s_elfName; }
    bool update_string();
};
#endif
```

cat base_class.cpp

```
#include "base_class.hpp"

bool program_base::update_string(){
    S<std::string>::s_elfName =  "UpdateString";
}
```

cat read_string.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "base_class.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main () {
    program_base pb; pb.update_string();
    cout << program_base::GetElfName() << endl;
}
```

The above one works fine, When I try to add templet inside the "class program_base"

cat base_class.hpp

```
#include <string>
#ifndef PROGRAM_BASE
#define PROGRAM_BASE
class program_base {
public:
    template <typename T>
    struct S
    {
        static std::string s_elfName;
    };
    template <typename T>
    std::string S<T>::s_elfName; //static initialization
    static std::string GetElfName() { return S<std::string>::s_elfName; }
    bool update_string();
};
#endif
```

it's giving an error as " error: member 's_elfName' declared as a template"

Why I'm not able to declare a template inside the class instead of inheriting it?

Comment: take the initialization of s_elfName out of the program_base class

Comment: `template <typename T> std::string program_base::S<T>::s_elfName;`

Comment: @masterop Why i can't initialize inside the class ?

Comment: because "Out-of-class definitions of the members of a nested class appear in the namespace of the enclosing class: ", [Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the C++ Std. Nested class declaration:

```
Member functions and static data members of a nested class can be defined in a namespace scope enclosingthe definition of their class.
[Example:
struct enclose {
  struct inner {
    static int x;
    void f(int i);
  };
};
int enclose::inner::x = 1;
void enclose::inner::f(int i) { /* ... */ }
— end example]
```

If you take the definition out of outer class then it should be fine:

```
template <typename T>
std::string program_base::S<T>::s_elfName;
```

Since C++17 you can also do inline static initializing:

```
class program_base {
public:
    template <typename T>
    struct S
    {
        inline static std::string s_elfName;
    };
    static std::string GetElfName() { return S<std::string>::s_elfName; }
    bool update_string();
};
```